# EXEC (@sql) does not work

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-insert, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure that executes

```
DECLARE 
    @PalabraResultante  VARCHAR(100),
    @FiltroAdicional    VARCHAR(MAX),
    @FiltroAdicional2   VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Sql                NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Sql = 'INSERT INTO TMP_SEMANTICA_OFERENTE (IdSede, IdProceso, Nombre, NombreEmpresa, Departamento, FechaInicio, DescripcionVacante, IdDepartamento, IdGrupoOcupacional1, IdGrupoOcupacional2, IdGrupoOcupacional3, IdSalarioRango, IdTipoContrato, IdNivelEstudio, IdJornada, IdIndustria, Titulo, Cargo1, Cargo2, Cargo3, TipoLocalizacion, LocalizacionId, Aplica, NombreCiudad, IdSesion, FechaInsercion)
            SELECT IdSede, IdProceso, Nombre, NombreEmpresa, Departamento, FechaInicio, DescripcionVacante, IdDepartamento, IdGrupoOcupacional1, IdGrupoOcupacional2, IdGrupoOcupacional3, IdSalarioRango, IdTipoContrato, IdNivelEstudio, IdJornada, IdIndustria, Titulo, Cargo1, Cargo2, Cargo3, TipoLocalizacion, LocalizacionId, Aplica, NombreCiudad, IdSesion, FechaInsercion
            FROM TMP_VACANTES_MATCHING_FILTRADO
            WHERE ((IdSesion = '''+@IdSesion+''') AND ('

SET @FiltroAdicional = ' OR ('
SET @FiltroAdicional2 = ' OR ('

DECLARE cBusqueda CURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@CadenaBusqueda,'')

OPEN cBusqueda
FETCH cBusqueda INTO @palabraResultante 

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) BEGIN
    SET @Sql = @Sql + ' CONTAINS(Nombre,'''+@palabraResultante+''') AND'
    SET @FiltroAdicional = @FiltroAdicional + ' CONTAINS(DescripcionVacante,'''+@palabraResultante+''') AND'
    SET @FiltroAdicional2 = @FiltroAdicional2 + ' CONTAINS(Titulo,'''+@palabraResultante+''') AND'

    FETCH cBusqueda INTO @palabraResultante
END

CLOSE cBusqueda
DEALLOCATE  cBusqueda

SET @Sql = SUBSTRING(@Sql,1,LEN(@Sql)-4)+')'
SET @FiltroAdicional = SUBSTRING(@FiltroAdicional,1,LEN(@FiltroAdicional)-4)+')'
SET @FiltroAdicional2 = SUBSTRING(@FiltroAdicional2,1,LEN(@FiltroAdicional2)-4)+')'

SET @Sql = @Sql + @FiltroAdicional+' '+@FiltroAdicional2  +' )'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

If I call this stored procedure with:

```
EXEC spName
```

it works fine

but when I call the stored procedure inside another stored procedure, it does not work.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: maybe there is an error in your syntax, try to print the output query, change `EXEC (@SQL)` to `PRINT (@SQL)`

Comment: the problem happens when i do delete from TMP_VACANTES_MATCHING_FILTRADO before to call the Store procedure, if dont it works but i do delete and after i do Insert, so when Store Procedure is executing there are data

Comment: Use [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) instead of `EXEC`. Print your query in the variable and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing a filter? But filters should be ORs (Name like '%'+@searchString+'%' OR Description like '%'+@searchString+'%'). Maybe I'm not correct in this.

Even so, look at the following pattern:

```
          INSERT INTO TMP_SEMANTICA_OFERENTE 
                    (IdSede,IdProceso,Nombre,NombreEmpresa,
                     Departamento,FechaInicio,Des0cripcionVacante,
                IdDepartamento,IdGrupoOcupacional1,
                11,IdGrupoOcupacional2, IdGrupoOcupacional3,IdSalarioRango,
                IdTipoContrato,IdNivelEstudio,IdJornada,IdIndustria,
               Titulo,
               Cargo1,
               Cargo2, 
               Cargo3,
               TipoLocalizacion, 
               LocalizacionId,
               Aplica,
               NombreCiudad,
               IdSesion,
               FechaInsercion)
                     SELECT IdSede,
                            IdProceso,
                            Nombre,
                            NombreEmpresa,
                            Departamento,
                            FechaInicio,
                            DescripcionVacante,
                            IdDepartamento,
                            IdGrupoOcupacional1,
                            IdGrupoOcupacional2,
                            IdGrupoOcupacional3,
                            IdSalarioRango,
                            IdTipoContrato,
                            IdNivelEstudio,
                            IdJornada,
                            IdIndustria,
                            Titulo,
                            Cargo1,
                            Cargo2,                                                                 
                            Cargo3,
                            TipoLocalizacion,
                            LocalizacionId,
                            Aplica,
                            NombreCiudad,
                            IdSesion,
                            FechaInsercion
                            FROM TMP_VACANTES_MATCHING_FILTRADO                 
                            WHERE ((IdSesion = @IdSesion) 
                                 AND EXISTS 
                                   (SELECT 1 
                                   FROM dbo.Split(@CadenaBusqueda,'') Nombre
                                   WHERE CONTAINS(Nombre,@palabraResultante)
                             OR CONTAINS(DescripcionVacante,@palabraResultante)
                            OR CONTAINS(Titulo,@palabraResultante))
```

Answer (score 0):

I really didnt know what it happened

I just changed the order to call stored procedures and it works fine.